# NIFI: How to wait for all the previous processors to finish execution and then do something just once?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a scenario in NIFI where I have complex task executions happening in many different processors. I would like to append one more processor at the end of this flow. This processor wants to wait for all the processors to finish and then execute it(JUST ONCE!).

How would it be possible to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at the Wait/Notify processors for performing this type of coordination...

https://ijokarumawak.github.io/nifi/2017/02/02/nifi-notify-batch/

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.4.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.Wait/index.html

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.4.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.Notify/index.html

Comment: Apache links are dead, here are the new ones: [Wait](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.Wait/index.html)   [Notify](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.Notify/index.html)